# Многопоточность python3

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

Проблема, не пойму многопоточность. Мне нужно прочитать из файла IP адреса, отправить запрос и на ответ сервера выполнить условие. Вот собственно код. Как мне сделать так, чтоб мои потоки не попадали на один и тот же IP адресс, и как вообще завести это в многопоточность?)))

```
import requests
import threading

def vpnize(url):
    r = requests.get("http://"+url+"/index.asp", timeout=15)   
    if r.status_code == 200 or 401:
        print(url)
    else:
        print("Connection refused")

filepath = r'/root/Desktop/fuzzer/IPS'
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
  outext=[line.strip().split('\t') for line in file.readlines()]
newlist=[]
for router in outext:
  try:
    device_name=router[0]
    url = "".join(str(x) for x in router[0]+':''8080')
    vpnize(url)
    threads = []
    url1_thread = threading.Thread(target=vpnize, args=url)
    url2_threads2 = threading.Thread(target=vpnize, args=url)
    url2_threads3 = threading.Thread(target=vpnize, args=url)
    url2_threads4 = threading.Thread(target=vpnize, args=url)



    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()    



  except (IndexError, requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
      continue
```

Comment: Циклы `for thread in threads` бессмысленные, потому что проходятся по пустому списку

Comment: И вообще у вас в коде ну очень много ошибок. Возьмите учебник по Python и освежите свои знания, почитав его

Comment: Я понимаю, убрал пустой список, Если допустим у меня был бы один ип, и адреса не читались из файла я бы легко набросал, но тут не пойму как совместить все это со чтением из списка? Теперь появилсь ошибка - "vpnize() takes 1 positional argument but 18 were given"

Comment: А IP адреса в списке чем разделяются?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

urls = ["216.58.206.4", "5.255.255.77"]

def thread(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        new_thread = Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        new_thread.start()
    return wrapper

@thread
def vpnize(url):
    r = requests.get("http://"+url, timeout=15)   
    if r.status_code == 200 or 401:
        print(url, end="\n")
    else:
        print("Connection refused")

for url in urls:
    vpnize(url)

sleep(10)
```